# Modified source of custom view in library wont affect on XML layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, libraries

I'm using in my project this library with custom ImageView which is able to handle pinch zoom and double tap zoom events: https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview. I need to change in that library's source few things, because I want to use it with ViewPager. The problem is that the when I modifying source code of custom view in library and after this I adding this modified custom view to layout in XML file like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:gesture-image="http://schemas.polites.com/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#000000">
<com.polites.android.GestureImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    gesture-image:min-scale="0.75"
    gesture-image:max-scale="10.0"
    android:src="@drawable/image"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

my changes don't want to  appear, I'm breaking source code (for testing) by changing all values from 0 to 100, when I creating layout programatically my changes appears, and custom view works as i assumed, but when I definie layout in XML there's no effect, even if I clean up some java files of library from source code custom view in XML layout still works like there's no change in source.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Project => Clean` of both your main project and the library?

Comment: Mmh any chance you added the library as an external jar as well?

Comment: I added this library by Project Propeteries>Android, after adding library as external jar the result is the same

Comment: My guess was actually that you may have added both, jar and project library; if that's the case, the classes in the jar could be 'overriding' those in the project, so that your changes won't take effect. Please, double check your java build path and your libs folder.

Comment: The library is not doubled

Comment: Well, if nothing else works, I'd directly include the library classes in a package inside your project, and remove the reference to the library.